# POSIX message queues - Error on open: Invalid argument

Tags: c, linux, qt, message-queue

I have trouble with creating a message queue on linux. The error I'm getting is "Invalid argument". Another thing I have to mansion is that the code is a part of Qt project.

Common mistakes are the name does not start with (/) and the number of arg is not correct, but I have checked those!

here is the code that I'm trying to run:

```
#define MQ_TEST_PATH            "/test_queue"
#define MQ_MAX_MSG_SIZE         256
#define MQ_MAX_MSG_COUNT        20

struct mq_attr mqAttr;
mqAttr.mq_maxmsg = MQ_MAX_MSG_COUNT;
mqAttr.mq_msgsize = MQ_MAX_MSG_SIZE;

mq_unlink(MQ_TEST_PATH);

mode_t mode =  S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR;
int oflags = O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL;

mqd_t mqd;
mqd = mq_open(MQ_TEST_PATH, oflags, mode, &mqAttr);

if(mqd < 0){
    perror("Error on open");
    qDebug()<<mqd;
    return 0;
}

mq_close(mqd);
mq_unlink(MQ_TEST_PATH);
```

Output:

```
Error on open: Invalid argument
-1
```

Comment: When the last argument of mq_open is changed (the queue attributes) to NULL and it works. But I don't what the default values for the msg size and queue max length.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**man mq_open**

> `EINVAL` `O_CREAT`  was  specified  in  `oflag`, and `attr` was not `NULL`, but `attr->mq_maxmsg` or `attr->mq_msqsize` was invalid.  Both of these fields must be greater than zero. In a process that is unprivileged (does not have the `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` capability), `attr->mq_maxmsg` must be less  than  or  equal  to  the `msg_max`  limit

**man mq_overview**

>
    /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max

> The default value for msg_max is 10.

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem. Can I ask you how did you get the err EINVAL from the error code. And how can I make my project have the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability? I'm kind of new to linux.

Comment: use **errno** global variable to get an error after latest system call. see man errno, man perror. As for CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability - do you really need it? Probably the best solution is to check current limits before assigning the queue attributes (see man getrlimit). If you really need to change limit do it in separate script as a privileged user. You can write required values to /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max and /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msgsize_max (see man mq_overview)

Comment: `getrlimit(RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE, ...)` seems to give the max number of bytes occupied by queues. `/proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max` gives the max size of a message, but I can't find a reasonable way to read this value from my C program. Do you? Ideally I'd let the user set the message size, but limit it to this value.

Comment: `sudo setcap cap_sys_resource+eip  /path/to/your/elf` - most documents on _mq_ fail to mention this!